# Benefits of selecting Android Game in Unity Player Settings?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, settings

In Unity player settings there is an option called Android Game, i know that in the [manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PlayerSettingsAndroid.html) says

> "Android TV - Check this box to mark the output package (APK) will as
>   a game rather than a regular application"

[image: Project settings - Android Game]

But what is the real difference in selecting it? is there any screen / processor benefit? does it only runs if Android TV is selected?

Regards...

Answer (score 3):

> But what is the real difference in selecting it? is there any screen /
>   processor benefit?

By enabling Android Game, `android:isGame` meta-data flag is set to true then added to the AndroidManifest.

[meta-data](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/games/index.html#manifest) doc from the TV  section:

> The Android TV home screen displays games in a separate row from
>   regular apps. To make your game appear in the list of games, set this to true.

[meta-data](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html) doc from the non TV  section:

> Whether or not the application is a game. The system may group
>   together applications classifed as games or display them separately
>   from other applications.

It is used by the system to determine if this is a game or not then switch to Game Mode. Some TV or system seems automatically disable image enhancement to lower the response time when they detect that this is game.

> does it only runs if Android TV is selected?

No. It runs without the Android TV selected.